# API returns x-wp-doingitwrong... but I'm already returning true

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I get this header back from my WP custom endpoint:

```
x-wp-doingitwrong: register_rest_route (since 5.5.0; The REST API route definition for <code>jwt-auth/v1/token/validate</code> is missing the required <code>permission_callback</code> argument. For REST API routes that are intended to be public, use <code>__return_true</code> as the permission callback.)
```

But I'm allready returning true. This is my code:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'booking/v1', '/booking/', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'post_draft_booking',
        'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
  ) );
} );
```

Why am I getting this error?

BR Kresten

Comment: Don't forget that https://example.com is not the same as http://example.com. I this case this was the problem.